# Moving Group Policy Folder Redirection root path

Tags: group-policy, redirection, directory

I have all my users on my domain enabled for Folder Redirection and they all point to the same root path (Basic Redirection). [Here are the settings.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/231591/static%20links/folder_redir_basic.JPG)

I want to move only a subset of those users out to a subfolder of the root path such that i can apply different security permissions on said subfolder (and have them propagate into the users MyDocs folders). I have the user subset in another AD container so i'm set to apply a new GPO but whenever i try to apply another GPO with the new root path, it does not work. When i say 'it does not work' i mean when new users are created, their mapping works and a new folder appears in the subfolder of the old root, just as i like. But i want the *existing* folders (for those *existing* users in the subset) to be moved out to to subfolder also - and *that* does not work. [Here are the settings](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/231591/static%20links/folder_redir_basic_4subset.JPG) of the new GPO that i'm trying to apply to the subset container.

I dont know how, but for one test user i did get this partially working - i had the user created with only the original GP applied and when i logged the new user on for the 1st time the folder and mapping was created in the old root like it should be. Then i applied the new GPO to a container containing my test user and updated policy on the wkstn and logged on again. Somehow a new folder was created in the subfolder and the contents were copied across. I noted that the old folder was not removed, just flushed of its contents. The new folder was working and mapped with everything contained within. I don't know how i did this and i can't seem to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [this group-based folder direction](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/231591/static%20links/folder_redir_groups_solution.JPG) i was able to map the paths to the new share and ensure that the existing users were moved correctly from the old location to the new.